# Why is a wine glass shaped the way it is?

Tags: everyday-life, physical-chemistry

Why is a wine glass shaped the way it is? And why are there different shapes for different wines? Is this a tradition, or is there any scientific reason behind it?

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wine_glass#Shapes

Comment: Some of the "tasting" of wine is actually thru the nose.  Wine glasses are in part designed to deliver vapors to your nose and liquid to your tongue at the same time.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about social traditions and reasonings, general science with a tad of biology, and glass blowing. It is not about physics.

Answer (score 2):

A little bit of physics - but mostly just fashion.

Red wines (supposedly) need to oxidize to release the flavo(u)r so red wine glasses have wider necks to allow more air. White wines don't and so the glasses have narrower necks.

If there really was a significant difference then you would drink white wines from a sealed pouch through a straw and shake red wines like a cocktail. So it's probably now more a question of fashion and pretend insider knowledge.

Comment: _you would drink white wines from a sealed pouch through a straw and shake red wines like a cocktail_ Not really. If you used a straw you wouldn't be able to smell it properly (smell is much more sensitive than taste). And shaking it would mix the aromas. But I agree than the glass is not that important ($70 is just too much). Anyway, this is not Wine.SE